# kafka producer blocking on callback

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm testing the **async** send() in my kafka producer.
The cluster I want to connect to is offline.
My assumption would be that I send 10000 individual requests (lenght of listToSend) quickly.
Next the timeout (60s) would kick in and after 60 seconds I would see the callbacks hit me with `logger.error(s"failed to send record ${x._2}", e)`
However it seems to take forever for the method to finish.

That's why I added in the `logger.debug("test: am I sending data")` line.

It prints, then nothing happens for 60 seconds. I see the failed callback for the 1st record. And only then will it move on.

Is this normal behavior or am I missing something fundamental?

```
listToSend.foreach { x =>
        logger.debug("test: am I sending data")
        // note: I added this 'val future =' in an attempt to fix this, to no avail
        val future = producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, String](topic, x._2), new Callback {
          override def onCompletion(metadata: RecordMetadata, e: Exception) {

            if (e != null) {
              //todo: handle failed sends, timeouts, ...
              logger.error(s"failed to send record ${x._2}", e)
            }
            else { //nice to have: implement logic here, or call another method to process metadata
              logger.debug("~Callback success~")
            }
          }
        }
        )
      }
```

**note:** I do not want to block this code, I want to keep it async. However it seems to be blocking on the send() regardless.

Comment: You need to get the Future

Comment: isn't that blocking? I added "val future = " in an attempt to fix this, it wasn't originally there

Comment: `producer.send` returns a `Future[RecordMetadata]` (or something like that). You can call `val meta = future.get()` to actually do the block, as well as `producer.close`

Comment: But I don't want to block, that's the thing. It's blocking now, but I just want to "get rid" of my records fast and let the logic handle any kind of failures/downtime/...

Comment: Then you need to set acks to zero in the producer config and not use a Callback or assign the future

Comment: the whole reason I put that in, is to have visibility of what's going wrong. Otherwise, if I don't put that callback in, we could be running a job for days without even knowing we might have not set the brokers correctly. So this is by design? As I understand it, I only have 1 thread for each broker and that's blocked by the callback, even-though I thought I was doing "fire and forget"

Comment: If you want to "forget", you don't need a Callback to verify results, right? You can use multiple threads, which can communicate with multiple brokers. You're not sending a message key, so it'll be null and round robin over all partitions of a topic (ie multiple brokers). And if you get exceptions, those are logged internally by log4j, not completely necessary within your code

Comment: Let me rephrase that: In my "producer send call loop" I don't want to care yet, I just want my 10K records handled so I can go and fetch some more.
However in the callback part, I want to catch exceptions, log them or maybe in future handle them (i.e. send an email to me to tell me that 200 records have not been received due to timeouts/record size limits/...) I know that just an empty "send()" is fire & forget. But I want to know and maybe act upton misshaps that might occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parallelism I never figured out completely.

However it seems like my topic name (I had named it '[projectname here]_connection') was the issue.

Even though I didn't know of any reserved keywords in topic names, this behavior popped up.

Some further experimenting also brought up that a topic name with a trailing space can also cause this behavior. The producer will try to send it to this topic, but the Kafka cluster doesn't seem to know how to deal with it, causing these timeouts.

So for all of you who come across this issue, check/change your topic name before proceeding your troubleshooting.